# Android studio: Genymotion isn't running the app

Tags: android, genymotion, amd-processor

I set up a Hello World applicaiton with a single button. I can launch Genymotion from Android studio. The Android logo appears but the app doesn't appear anywhere. I feel I'm missing something obvious.

I'm using:

Genymotion plug-in 1.0.5
Android Studio 1.3.2
Virtual Box 4.3.30
Genymotion, with Windows 8.1.

I can't use the built-in Android AVDs because I have an AMD processor rather than Intel. I tried setting up a custom device but this won't run the app (no response). I've tried using my Android tablet to run the app on, but this won't work either.

Thanks for your help. 
[image: Android studio with 'Hello world']

Comment: When you click the run button (the green triangle in the toolbar), what actually happens?

Comment: Hi, I get the 'choose device' dialogue and see the Genymotion tablet.

Comment: Select your device and then click run.

Comment: Didn't work, I'm afraid.

Comment: You need to find the logcat on android studios and see if you can resolve the error from there.